# Prevent redux access from browser

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react application that have different scenarios. For almost everything, one user has to be logged in.

I noticed that if I use the dispatcher option of the [redux devTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) I can dispatch whatever I want. I can even go to the pages where only the logged user can access.

Is there any option to prevent this? I don't want to let anyone to modify redux state. Should i put "is logged" conditions everywhere?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, putting isLogged in options is not going to seem like a good option.

You can check whether or not you are in production mode in order to enable or disable the `redux-dev-tools` in the browser. like below while you are inside of your create store function:

```
const composeEnhancers =
  (nodeEnv !== 'production' &&
    typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
  compose;

export default createStore(
  YOUR_REDUCER,
  composeEnhancers(PUT_YOUR_MIDDLEWARES)
);
```

So in Production mode, no one even would be able to access any kind of redux-related function from the browser, since it is not even going to be exposed to the `window` object.

Comment: With the caveat of: with a breakpoint at the right position, everybody will always be able to access everything. So let's say, it will not be accessible *easily* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should think about why you want this. With enough work, an user can always do everything with your application because it is on **their** machine, in **their** browser.
If something should be "safe" from the user, it has to happen on the server, out of their reach.

Doing stuff like this is only going to make it more difficult to debug a project you might have in production where a bug only appears in prod.
If a user messes with your application and it crashes, it is not your responsibility any more.